# How do we report bugs and typos for the site?

Tags: support

This is a general question for all stack exchange sites.

Comment: I can't tell if you're providing a static question, or are really asking where to put bugs and typos.

Comment: Okay, this is not the dumbest question I've asked here... yeah, I was just curious... didn't really see anything that stood out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You report them here, on meta.